# Is there a compilation of the loading tips?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm looking for a list of all the tips shown on the loading screen.

Comment: Be aware that some tips begin to appear only after certain events, thus this compilation might be a minor spoiler for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a list [here](http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/1100/1/Skyrim-loading-screen-tips-hints-and-lore---Song-of-the-Dragonborn/Page1.html), but note that it's the first page of five.  The links to the rest of the pages can be found lower down on the page.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize there's so many; thanks!

Comment: I believe there are even some missing in that list.

Answer (score 4):

A full list of all 129 loading tips, including the corresponding images can be seen in this album:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV4Z4.jpg